# GitLab Runner running Windows Docker Image can't access Repository

Tags: windows, git, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm trying to run a local GitLab runner on my machine. Whenever a push occurs to a certain repo, a docker image is run, and a bunch of commands are run inside the container to test the code. So I set up a GitLab runner on my machine, and I keep getting this error message in GitLab when a build is triggered:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.donkey.com/core/cow.git/': Could not resolve host: git.donkey.com
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 128
```

I have my runner configuration set up in the following way:

```toml
[[runners]]
  name = "cow"
  url = "https://git.donkey.com/"
  token = "RANDOMKEY"
  executor = "docker-windows"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "donkey-images.artifactory.donkey.com/donkey-builder-images:chicken-4.0.0"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["c:\\cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

I can't figure out what's going on here. I've tried various suggestions, such as adding a `clone_url`, an `extra_host`, and a `dns` to no avail. Anyone experience something like this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I just needed to add my IP address to `dns` and `dns_search`.